# xdg-mime and file command identifying file type differently

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome3, mime-types

If you look at the screenshot bellow you will find that gnome is telling a file which is ASCII text as audio/x-mod.

[image]

For the time being I have set

`audio/x-mod=codium.desktop` in `mimeapps.list`, but I do not think it is a good solution.

How does gnome identify file type (`file` command identify it correctly, so I am assuming gnome is not using it). How can I fix this issue?

**Update 1:**

```
% file --mime git.fish
git.fish: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
% xdg-mime query filetype git.fish
audio/x-mod
```

`xdg-mime` does not give the same result as `file --mime`. I can confirm that, in this case `file --mime` is right and
`xdg-mime` is wrong.

Comment: What's the output of `file --mime` for that file? Also please post the output as text.

Comment: The output is `git.fish: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: Created a bug report https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdgmime/-/issues/33